# SQL - Display two counts as columns from same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I'm new to writing sql and stuck on an issue. Here is my query:

```
select count(*) as new_column1
  from table1
 where column1 = 'x' and column2 = 'y' and column3 = 'z'`
```

and

```
 select count(*) as new_column2
 from table 1
 where column1 = 'xx' and column2 = 'yy' and column3 = 'zz'
```

The result for query two display below query 1.  How would I get the result for query 2 next to the result for query 1? Using SQL Server Management Studio 2008. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when column1 = 'x' and column2 = 'y' and column3 = 'z' then 1 else 0
           end) as new_column1,
       sum(case when column1 = 'xx' and column2 = 'yy' and column3 = 'zz' then 1 else 0
           end) as new_column2
from table1 ;
```

If you happen to have a composite index on all three columns, then the following approach is likely to be faster:

```
select (select count(*)
        from table1
        where column1 = 'x' and column2 = 'y' and column3 = 'z'
       ) as new_column1,
       (select count(*) 
        from table 1
        where column1 = 'xx' and column2 = 'yy' and column3 = 'zz'
       ) as as new_column2;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking to generate.  Thank you!